# помогите доработать скрипт открытия модальных окон

Tags: javascript, html, html5

я написал скрипт для открытия модальных окон, он практически работает, только вот открывает не то (другое) окно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать открытие окон. Ошибка заключается во 2 части js кода, в блоке if()

```js
var closeModal = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
var modalWindows = document.getElementsByClassName('works-description');
for (var i = 0; i < closeModal.length; i++) {
    closeModal[i].onclick = function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < modalWindows.length; j++) {
            modalWindows[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
var openElement = document.getElementsByClassName('openingFigure');
for (var s = 0; s < openElement.length; s++) {
    openElement[s].onclick = function openModalWindow () {
        for (var m = 0; m < modalWindows.length; m++) {
            var modalWindowAttributes = modalWindows[m].getAttribute('data-window');
            if (modalWindowAttributes == openElement[s]) {
                modalWindows[0].style.display = 'flex';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.work-cards-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
figure {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 370px;
    height: 270px;
    background: #000;
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
figure h2 {
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: translateY(15px);
}
figure p {
    transition: 0.1s;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    visibility: hidden;
}
figure:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
figure:hover:before,
figure:hover:after {
    transform: scale(1);
}
figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: scaleY(0);
}
figure:hover h2,
figure:hover p {
    transform: translateY(0);
    visibility: visible
}
.close {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 22px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}
.works-description h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.works-description img {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 316px;
}
.works-description {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
    display: none;
}
.works-description-block {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #94969E;
    width: 70%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.works-description-text {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.works-description-text h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 546;
}
.works-description-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.works-description-text a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #94969E;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #94969E;
    width: 240px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
            <div class="work-cards-container">
                <figure class="wow fadeInLeft batsam-figure openingFigure" id="batsam">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Batsam</h2>
                        <p>Дизайн, верстка</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="wow fadeInRight moroz-figure openingFigure" id="moroz">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Сайт Деда Мороза</h2>
                        <p>Верстка</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="batsamWindow" data-window="0" class="works-description">
                <div class="works-description-block">
                    <a id="close" data-close="0" class="close">&#10006;</a>
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="img/mini-batsam-bg.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="works-description-text">
                        <h2>Batsam Cofee</h2>
                        <h3>Задача</h3>
                        <p>Сделать редизайн страницы</p>
                        <h3>Сроки</h3>
                        <p>5 дней</p>
                        <h3>Бюджет: 5 тыс. рублей</h3>
                        <a href="http://coffee.podarok.click/">Перейти на сайт</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="morozWindow" data-window="1" class="works-description">
                <div class="works-description-block">
                    <a id="close-moroz" data-close="1" class="close">&#10006;</a>
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="img/moroz-bg.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="works-description-text">
                        <h2>Сайт деда мороза</h2>
                        <h3>Задача</h3>
                        <p>Сделать частичный редизайн страницы</p>
                        <h3>Сроки</h3>
                        <p>1 день</p>
                        <h3>Бюджет: 1 тыс. рублей</h3>
                        <a href="http://moroz.podarok.click/">Перейти на сайт</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае нет абсолютно никакой необходимости в этих мудрёных циклах. Вполне достаточно получить список элементов, которые должны будут открывать Ваши модальные окна, повесить на них обработчики, которые получают id целевого модального окна из дата-атрибута (`destinationId` в данном случае), затем при клике получать тот самый `div` и менять его стили.
Для закрытия в циклах тоже необходимости нет - получаем необходимого родителя (в Вашем случае - `work-description`) и присваиваем ему `display: none;`.

```js
var closeModal = document.getElementsByClassName('close');

Array.from(closeModal, closeButton => {
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none');
}); 



var openElement = document.getElementsByClassName('openingFigure');

Array.from(openElement, openButton => {
  openButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let modalId = e.target.dataset.destinationId;
    document.getElementById(modalId).style.display = 'flex';
  });
});
```

```css
.work-cards-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
figure {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 370px;
    height: 270px;
    background: #000;
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
figure h2 {
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: translateY(15px);
}
figure p {
    transition: 0.1s;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    visibility: hidden;
}
figure:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
figure:hover:before,
figure:hover:after {
    transform: scale(1);
}
figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: scaleY(0);
}
figure:hover h2,
figure:hover p {
    transform: translateY(0);
    visibility: visible
}
.close {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 22px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}
.works-description h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.works-description img {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 316px;
}
.works-description {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
    display: none;
}
.works-description-block {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #94969E;
    width: 70%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.works-description-text {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.works-description-text h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 546;
}
.works-description-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.works-description-text a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #94969E;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #94969E;
    width: 240px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-cards-container">
                <figure class="wow fadeInLeft batsam-figure openingFigure"
                data-destination-id="batsamWindow"
                id="batsam">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Batsam</h2>
                        <p>Дизайн, верстка</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="wow fadeInRight moroz-figure openingFigure" data-destination-id="morozWindow" id="moroz">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Сайт Деда Мороза</h2>
                        <p>Верстка</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div id="batsamWindow" data-window="0" class="works-description">
                <div class="works-description-block">
                    <a id="close" data-close="0" class="close">&#10006;</a>
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="img/mini-batsam-bg.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="works-description-text">
                        <h2>Batsam Cofee</h2>
                        <h3>Задача</h3>
                        <p>Сделать редизайн страницы</p>
                        <h3>Сроки</h3>
                        <p>5 дней</p>
                        <h3>Бюджет: 5 тыс. рублей</h3>
                        <a href="http://coffee.podarok.click/">Перейти на сайт</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="morozWindow" data-window="1" class="works-description">
                <div class="works-description-block">
                    <a id="close-moroz" data-close="1" class="close">&#10006;</a>
                    <div class="img-block">
                        <img src="img/moroz-bg.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="works-description-text">
                        <h2>Сайт деда мороза</h2>
                        <h3>Задача</h3>
                        <p>Сделать частичный редизайн страницы</p>
                        <h3>Сроки</h3>
                        <p>1 день</p>
                        <h3>Бюджет: 1 тыс. рублей</h3>
                        <a href="http://moroz.podarok.click/">Перейти на сайт</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Немного доработал ваш скрипт и все заработало.